# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Unusual case

Tags: django, django-forms, django-csrf

I suppose that the problem of this error is hidden in template. Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal loginFrm" action="/login/" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="control-group">                               
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name = "username">
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name = "password">
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign in">
            </form>     

            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
```

And my `login` view:

```
def login(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            args['username'] = username
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/',args,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my last project, it worked correctly. But here is this error.

Comment: did you referred https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it ? and  configured csrf

Comment: How do you output the login form?  Do you use the `render_to_response()` shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

View the html source on your page with the rendered login form and confirm that you have a hidden field with the csrf token.

Something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='NzYXoXbN9beogdB6gf22rNXkTNQd6Jri' />
```

It's possible that the view you have is not passing the context_instance. It depends which method you are using to render the view in the first place.

You could use:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or the easier render() which will automatically use RequestContext

```
return render(request, 'my_template.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

as a case you can use [ensure_csrf_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) view decorator.